# How can use conditions in rewrite in htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am using this code in my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?type=category&category=$1&subcategory=$2 [L]
```

but if i enter this url:

```
domain.com/category/example-category
```

it have 404 error. I must enter url:

```
domain.com/category/example-category/sub-category-example
```

I want if enter url:

```
domain.com/category/example-category
```

to rewrite to

```
domain.com/index.php?type=category&category=example-category
```

without 404 error

And if enter

```
domain.com/category/example-category/sub-category-example
```

to rewrite to

```
domain.com/index.php?type=category&category=example-category&subcategory=sub-category-example
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?type=category&category=$1 [L]
```